# my_ip/phpmyadmin shows 404 Not Found on Nginx and after one tutorial instead loading my website it downloads a file

Tags: php, ubuntu, nginx

Trying to install phpMyAdmin on Nginx. Following all tutorials carefully, but when head my website `my_IP/phpmyadmin` I get 404 Not Found anyway.
And when I was loading my website by typing my IP address I got my website. But after following [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9wm33sz6oe4) instead of showing my website my browser downloads file "download". I deletted that code piece from tutorial, restarted Nginx, but browser still downloads a "download" file instead of heading my website. And when I type `my_IP/phpmyadmin` I still get 404 Not Found.
How I can get my settings back and run phpMyAdmin on my Nginx server?
Here is `/etc/nginx/sites-available/default` settings:

```
    server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    # SSL configuration
    #
    # listen 443 ssl default_server;
    # listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;
    #
    # Note: You should disable gzip for SSL traffic.
    # See: https://bugs.debian.org/773332
    #
    # Read up on ssl_ciphers to ensure a secure configuration.
    # See: https://bugs.debian.org/765782
    #
    # Self signed certs generated by the ssl-cert package
    # Don't use them in a production server!
    #
    # include snippets/snakeoil.conf;

    root /var/www/html;

    # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
    index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name _;

    location / {
            # First attempt to serve request as file, then
            # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
            try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    # pass PHP scripts to FastCGI server
    #
    location ~ \.php$ {
            include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    #
    #       # With php-fpm (or other unix sockets):
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php8.1-fpm.sock;
    #       # With php-cgi (or other tcp sockets):
    #       fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    }

    # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
    # concurs with nginx's one
    #
    location ~ /\.ht {
            deny all;
    }
    location /phpmyadmin {
       root /usr/share/;
       index index.php index.html index.htm;
       location ~ ^/phpmyadmin/(.+\.php)$ {
               try_files $uri =404;
               root /usr/share/;
               fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php8.1-fpm.sock;
               fastcgi_index index.php;
               fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
               include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
       }
       location ~* ^/phpmyadmin/(.+\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|css|png|js|ico|html|xml|txt))$ {
               root /usr/share/;
       }
    }

}
```

**UPD:**
Updated my `PHP8.1`, uncommented some important code pieces and added `location /phpmyadmin` code piece from [that tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9wm33sz6oe4).
Looks like page is loading correctly, but my_IP/phpmyadmin still loads 404 Not Found.

Comment: Even if this is not related to programming: as far as I see, your configuration does not contain any path mapping for phpMyAdmin. How should nginx know where you've installed it?

Comment: @NicoHaase, just updated my post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured it out myself.
Actually in directory `/etc/nginx/sites-available/` I already had two files, `default` and `my_website.com`. That piece of code I put into `default`. But now I moved this code to `my_website.com` file and it worked:

```
location /phpmyadmin {
   root /usr/share/;
   index index.php index.html index.htm;
   location ~ ^/phpmyadmin/(.+\.php)$ {
           try_files $uri =404;
           root /usr/share/;
           fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php8.1-fpm.sock;
           fastcgi_index index.php;
           fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
           include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
   }
   location ~* ^/phpmyadmin/(.+\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|css|png|js|ico|html|xml|txt))$ {
           root /usr/share/;
   }
}
```

Thank you for attention!